# How to make keyboard shortcuts work for the Clipmenu application?

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste

I'm using [Clipmenu](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29988/clipmenu) application to manage copy and paste tasks.

It seems to me that you can use the shortcuts: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to paste the copied texts, but it doesn't work though.

Let's say I copy these 4 lines in 4 times:

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

Then I'd like to use the shortcuts to paste every one of them. This is:

```
cmd + 1 (to paste '111111')
cmd + 2 (to paste '222222') 

and so on..
```

But if I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> I just hear a sound and nothing happens.

Comment: Which application are you trying to paste into? I've found issues with some other clipboard handlers in certain applications, but it works in others. You could also try pressing Cmd + V after Cmd + 1 and see if it pastes the data then.

Comment: I'm trying to paste into a textedit file. What you say sounds to conflicts when different apps use the same shortcuts, but no shortcuts are assigned to the textedit app

Answer (score 3):

Invoke clip menu first (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by default) then use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> to paste that particular item.